# jquery issue with mouseenter() + animate()

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, fadein, mouseenter

Inside a div .frame I have 3 others div: `.top`, `.middle` and `.bottom`.

`.top` and `.bottom` are in `display none`, and when the mouse is over `.frame`, with the jquery function `animate`, the height of `.frame` is increasing and `.top` and `.bottom` are showing with `.fadeIn()`.

When the mouse is out `.frame`, the size of `.frame` is decreasing and `.top` and `.bottom` are going away with `.fadeOut()`.

My CSS are:

```
.frame{
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        position: absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:50px;
    }

    .middle{
        width:100%;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .top{
        display:none;
        background-color:red;
        width:100%;
    }

    .bottom{
        position:absolute;
        display:none;
        bottom:0px;
        background-color:red;
        width:100%;
    }
```

my HTML:

```
<div class="frame">
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="middle">middle</div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom<br>bottom<br>bottom<br>bottom</div>
</div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {
        var el = $(this),
            top = el.children('.top'),
            bottom = el.children('.bottom'),
            middle = el.children('.middle'),
            d = bottom.height()+20,
            mEnt = e.type == "mouseenter";

        if(mEnt == true){
            middle.stop().animate({'top':'20px'});
            el.stop().animate({
                'height':'+='+d,
                'top':'-=20'
            }); 
            top.stop().fadeIn(300);
            bottom.stop().fadeIn(300);
        }else{
            middle.stop().animate({'top':'0px'});
            el.stop().animate({
                'height':'-='+d,
                'top':'+=20'
            });
            top.stop().fadeOut(300);
            bottom.stop().fadeOut(300);
        }
    });
```

here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/Y6cbQ/

It's working well, but when the mouse is entering and leaving fast it's messing the whole thing. I put a `.stop()` before all `.animate()` but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Why did you post the same question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.stop()` use `.stop(true, true)`. This makes it so the queue of animations is cleared and the current animation finishes immediately (http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

You can see in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3gYtK/

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {
    var el = $(this),
        top = el.children('.top'),
        bottom = el.children('.bottom'),
        middle = el.children('.middle'),
        d = bottom.height()+20,
        mEnt = e.type == "mouseenter";

    if(mEnt == true){
        middle.stop().animate({'top':'20px'});
        el.stop(true, true).animate({
            'height':'+='+d,
            'top':'-=20'
        }); 
        top.stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
        bottom.stop(true, true).fadeIn(300);
    }else{
        middle.stop().animate({'top':'0px'});
        el.stop(true, true).animate({
            'height':'-='+d,
            'top':'+=20'
        });
        top.stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);
        bottom.stop(true, true).fadeOut(300);
    }
});
```